# Puzzling SE's Annual Advent Calendar 2016

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story, visual, seasonal, imgur-maze

It had finally arrived! PSE's annual Christmas advent calendar for 2016! The one thing  that I had been waiting for all year!

I tore open the packaging and let out a delighted gasp at this year's new look. Tentatively I reached for the first door, and tore it off, hardly able to keep in my enthusiasm. But this year, I was disappointed...

Instead of finding an incredibly detailed, small drawing which would have me mesmerized, there was just a letter. A plain, black letter on a plain, white background. In a state of panic, I tore off all the other doors, hoping, praying that the others wouldn't be the same. But each door I tore off, revealed a letter.

I collected up all the doors and flung them into the fire, before curling into a ball and starting to cry.

When my painful, wracking sobs had subsided, a revelation hit me. There had only been 23 doors. I checked the calendar again, but couldn't find a 24th door anywhere. Which could only mean one thing.

In true puzzling fashion, the 24th door had been hidden somewhere in part of the calendar. But I had just burnt all the doors, which surely would have been clues. Nevertheless, I was determined that those smug Puzzlers who made this monstrosity of an advent calendar, would not outdo me.

[image]

I turned it over and also found a note scrawled on the back. It said

> *Apologies, we appear to have made a mistake and put two 18's. The first should be an 8. Sorry for the inconvenience.*

So not only had they made a bad advent calendar, they'd made a broken one too! Well I got to work and to start with I wrote them down to look at:

```
A g e t l
N U a i s
b i v o v
t h D R i 
  n s O
```

> ## Can you help me find the 24<sup>th</sup> image?

Comment: Please note that PSE does NOT sell Advent Calendars, and the puzzle above is a complete fabrication. (Sadly)

Comment: Aaah yes, top right corner is lowecase L, not uppercase I

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Is the case of the letters presented by IAmInPLS correct? Hard to see in some cases.

Comment: @Mithrandir I'd prefer it if you did so in one of my old posts

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The missing door is - >

> [image]

Explanation -

> Taking the capital letters we get A,N,D,U,R,O making it **AROUND**

Hence -

> Zooming 'around' the image we get the following letters ->        
>    [image] Lower case s
>  [image] Letter G
>  [image] Letter O
>  [image] Letter N
>    [image] Letter P

Which gives -

> **sGONP**. The down arrow serves as a double hint. Giving us - >    
>  [image] 
> Thanks @Will for quickly pointing it out in TSL.

Next...

> Using an [online bar-code reader](https://online-barcode-reader.inliteresearch.com/), for reading the following barcode, we get **13 - 12 - 10 - 9 - 4** 
>  [image]

More findings -

> Looking at the image, there are all the numbers 1-23, except 8. There are two 18s, but the note scrawled on the back says this is a mistake so the first 18 is an 8.
>
> ```
> 3-11-17 2-16
> 10-14-7 9-1
> 15-21-8 22-18
> 5-6-12 4-19
> 23 20-13
> ```

So,

> Arranging the letters using the values in an ascending order gives - > 
>  **start having double vision**
>  If we use 'double vision' and use the decoded bar-code numbers on the original letters and the rearranged letters, we get
>
> **visit ODNiR**

So

> ODNiR is and imgur code giving

The Door!

> [image]